# I have a timeseries plot of volumes. Want to impose another column of dataframe as dashed lines on it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a pandas df that looks like:

```
         date total any_esc
0   2018-04-01  1   0.0
1   2018-04-02  1   0.0
2   2018-04-03  4   1.0
3   2018-04-04  5   1.0
4   2018-04-05  10  1.0

I plotted the timeseries as:
df.plot('date', 'total')
```

Now I want to impose any_esc on the plot.
Whenever any_esc = 1, I want there to be a dashed vertical line at that date.

I tried plotting total and any_esc on y-axis, however that did not help as it also plots the zeros.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot vertical lines, use [`axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html):

```
# The main plot
ax = df.plot.line(x='date', y='total')

# The vertical lines
for _, row in df.query('any_esc == 1').iterrows():
    ax.axvline(row['date'], linestyle='--')
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi, Sorry I want date and total to be a line plot. when I use this code with a line plot, it doesn't work

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that generates the line plot?

Comment: df.plot('date', 'total') does that

Comment: The difference is the value of the x-axis. In a bar chart, the x-axis is numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. In a line plot, the x-axis is the date values